# Is C collation suitable for my Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am working with 500m rows (120GB) in Postgres 9.4, and I am trying to make SELECT statements as fast as possible. I am less concerned about the speed of INSERT and UPDATE, because my data only changes once a quarter and I'll probably use a backup database and switch over when that happens.

I'm working on a Debian Wheezy server, with 32GB of RAM and 320GB of solid-state. I have set `maintenance_work_mem` to 16GB while setting up the database, and `shared_buffers` to 12GB.

I have found that [creating indexes is slow](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95496/recommended-postgres-settings-to-speed-up-indexing-on-a-100gb-database), and even with indexes, `SELECT` queries are still quite slow. To help this, I've been recommended to use the C collation for the database.

I've been reading through [the collation documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/collation.html), but it doesn't answer all my questions. So here's what I want to do with my database:

- Support fast `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1='020406AAA'` queries.
- Support fast `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1 LIKE '02%'` queries.
- Allow non-ASCII characters in some columns (e.g. `Ménière's disease`). This isn't absolutely critical, though - I could convert these to ASCII if it would really help for speed.
- Add the PostGIS extensions to the database.

Are any of these contra-indications for using the C collation?

I'm expecting all the columns where I want to use `LIKE` queries to consist of digits and uppercase letters only.

The data is a UK dataset, in English, for UK-only users. So I'm not expecting to have to add internationalization.

Answer (score 1):

From what you're describing, it doesn't sound like anything is contraindicated related to the C collation order. In fact, Robert Haas, has a great discussion on the subject here, which seems to come to the conclusion that if you don't need locale aware sorting, just don't use it: [Perils of Collation Aware Comparisons](http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2012/03/perils-of-collation-aware-comparisons.html)

I did notice you are on Debian Wheezy. The stock kernel for Debian Wheezy is 3.2, which if you're using that, has abysmal performance on database workloads. I would investigate that along with the collation testing, if you are not happy with the performance of your machine.

The wheezy-backports kernel is 3.16, which does not have these issues. Discussion and performance tests are here: [Benchmarking PostgreSQL with Different Kernel Versions](http://medium.com/postgresql-talk/benchmarking-postgresql-with-different-linux-kernel-versions-on-ubuntu-lts-e61d57b70dd4)

Hope that helps. =)