# Recommended postgres parameters for index creation with 244gb RAM and 32 CPUs?

Tags: postgresql, performance, aws, postgresql-10, aurora, postgresql-performance

I have a 200 GB database with 26 tables that I need to create indexes on.

Currently index creation takes a long time on the biggest tables, as they have ~12gb and 400,000,000 rows in them (>4 hours).

I've set `maintenance_work_mem` to 100gb, and set `max_parallel_workers` to 30.

Are there any other parameters I should tune to improve the index creation speed?

This is on AWS Aurora, using postgres-10.6, in case that makes a difference.

There is no one else using the database and downtime/full locks are fine.

Comment: Note: I've read this answer already, as well https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95496/recommended-postgres-settings-to-speed-up-indexing-on-a-100gb-database, but it's a bit outdated and does not have a complete answer

Answer (score 1):

> This is on AWS Aurora, using postgres-10.6, in case that makes a difference.

Yes, this matters quite a lot.  Native parallel btree index builds were introduced in v11, so your "max_parallel_workers" setting won't matter for index builds under v10.

Unless you upgrade, you will have to parallelize them yourself by opening multiple sessions in parallel and building one index in each one.  You will probably want to lower "maintenance_work_mem" as well if you have parallel processes (either of the manual or the v11 variety) as each one can claim that much memory.

Comment: He can't upgrade (yet). The latest Aurora Postgres 2.2 is based on Postgres 10.6. Their storage system has its own parallelization - independent from Postgres' parallel implementation. I am not sure how that interacts with `max_parallel_workers` exactly, but overall it massively outperforms RDS Postgres (even v11) in writing activity - with the notable exception of building indexes, where both are on par from what I have seen so far. Unfortunate for the particular task of the OP.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the difference between Aurora and RDS on version availability.  I would expect parallel workers to be beneficial only for their CPU parallelism, not IO parallelism.  I was assuming he had enough IO available so that CPU would be limiting--although if it were to parallelize 30-ways, maybe that is not a good assumption.